# What am I doing wrong in this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Does somebody see what I do wrong in this query:

```
$subgroup_query_test = "Select Sex, Age From ten_miles 
                                         Where Age <= 29 
                                         AND   Age >= 25 
                                         AND   Sex ='$details_person_sex' 
                                         AND  Av_speed >= '$details_person_av_speed' ";
$results5 = mysqli_query($db, $subgroup_query_test);
```

For one reason or another I get way too many results.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: echo $subgroup_query_test;

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the query but you need to provide more info what is not working like any error etc.

Comment: add `LIMIT {num}` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Comment: i think this query is completely correct and you really have too many results in your table

Comment: There is something wrong with the last statement of Av_speed

Comment: No for one reason or another, he doesn't filter on a numeric value. The field Av_speed is a decimal in my SQL data base, properly named, I don't get what I do wrong...

Comment: But the other filters work, for sure it is the last restricition that is wrong.

Comment: Maybe because it's a string?

Comment: I tried with a numeric value, Av_speed >= 25, didn't work either

Comment: Can you show us an interpolated query?

Comment: 1. echo $subgroup_query_test;
2. What is the expected result? how many records? it's is a big table? could you put a few records on a table and test the query

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help everybody, I am looking already a couple of hours at the problem and I can't find it, so I used this way around, which works:

```
    $subgroup_query_test = "Select Sex, Age, Av_speed From ten_miles 
    Where Age <= 29 AND Age >= 25 AND  Sex ='$details_person_sex'";

    $results4 = mysqli_query($db, $subgroup_query_test);

    while($details_age_group = mysqli_fetch_array($results4)){
        $Ages[] = $details_age_group['Sex'];
        if ($details_age_group['Av_speed'] > $details_person_av_speed ){
            $faster[]=1;
            $slower[]=0;
        }else{
            $faster[]=0;
            $slower[]=1;
        }
    };
```

Hope you are not too disappointed I gave up, I really do not know why the query with average age did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: which data_type do you use for the column av_speed?

Comment: decimal(4,2) is in SQL

Comment: could you echo query and post it? could you post the table structure and some data ??